# Domain controller on VMware

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, vmware-workstation, domain

I have installed windows server 2008 r2, two clones of windows xp and one cent os on my vmware workstation 11.0.

I want windows server 2008 R2 to behave as an DC which has AD,DHCP & DNS from which the other three virtual machines namely two xp clones and 1 cent os should integrate with.

I have problem with the virtual network configuration, can someone please tell what setting should be on the network adapter on vmware on all the machines including DC.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: "I have problem with ..." is not a question. Please write what exactly your problem is. Also, VMware Workstation has a PDF manual. Make sure you have studied that before posting here.

Comment: What settings you use are entirely up to you.

Answer (score 1):

For optimal auto-discovery and whatnot, the Domain Controller should provide DHCP (optional) and DNS (required) services to domain members.

Simply use an otherwise unused virtual network (like VMnet4) for connecting the machines.

The Domain Controller will act as a router and provide Internet access, so it also needs a path to the physical network, e.g. via NAT. That means it will have two virtual NICs.